# Is Thread.sleep a good way to simulate HTTP request for testing purposes?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a system that relies heavily on network IO requests. I'd like to make a reliable  performance test. One naive way could be to put the thread to sleep for some time.

My question is if the fact that I'm putting a thread to sleep is equal to a thread being blocked on an HTTP request?

I'm asking it with a perspective of [Thread Lifecycle](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-lifecycle). Theoretically speaking, if an HTTP request would take a constant and known amount of time, would that be equal to a Thread.sleep?

In other words, would test results be the same? (To some extent of course, since scheduling is considered indeterministic)

Comment: This question feels way too vague. If you just want to simulate delays on per-thread connections, it could work. If you want to be as close to actual HTTP requests as possible, meaning you also want to simulate connections being bound, bandwidth, fluctuations, long-running requests, malicious requests etc., this might not be good enough

Comment: Yes, my main goal is to simulate the delay itself.

Comment: Then yes, using `Thread.sleep` seems like a suitable substitute if the thread would block on a socket read otherwise

Answer (score 1):

It is not so clear what you are trying to test here.

Generally speaking, using `Thread.sleep()` is not a good practice in tests.

If you are testing your application, then you should mock the other endpoint that you are calling using a mock server.

Comment: Does your advice also apply if the OP is writing a performance test instead of a unit test ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad practice to use Thread sleep in order to simulate http calls. It's much better to use real http calls. If you can't send real http requests to remote services you can simulate these services using wiremock

http://wiremock.org/

Comment: That depends on the context: If the OP just wants to run an experiment from the command line, then there's nothing wrong with using `sleep()` to simulate a blocking call.  But if the OP wants to write _unit tests_, then it becomes highly desirable to design the application such that a test can simulate the passage of time by bumping some simulated clock forward instead of actually delaying the test for that amount of time.